# What is the source of Pokéstops and Gym trivia

Tags: pokemon-go

I found some Pokéstops and Gyms with rather odd sounding descriptions. One spot, for example, was a classical statue of a woman with exposed breast. The description sounded like it was created by either some lusty 15 year olds or some high level trolls.

So my question is what is the source of these location informations. I've heard they're the the same spots as in the game Ingress. But even then, is all location information provided by Ingress/Pokémon Go users, or is a public database containing photos with location data being used (eg. Panoramio or similair).

Comment: In my village everything is called "Ohio" which is a term that is sometimes used by kids to refer to it since it sounds cooler than the actual name.

Answer (score 1):

People used to be able to upload these spots in Ingress, if you want any spots added now you have to send an email.